# Claculating Sum(Expression) in SSRS

Tags: .net, reporting-services, expression

I have put expression at Detail field:

```
=iif(Fields!ExRate.Value > 0,
     (Fields!ExRate.Value * Fields!SubsAmt.Value),
     Fields!SubsAmt.Value)
```

I want to take this field's sum at the bottom.
How to take sum of this field containing expression?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution here is to create a calculated column, and sum on that.
I think there is a solution using `sum`, but I'm not sure it is worth the effort - I find  calculated columns more readable, and they avoid duplicated logic (which you have on the column and the summary row).